# How to access off-screen but existing cells in UICollectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

The title might be a little hard to understand, but this situation might help you with it.

I'm writing a multiple image picker. Say the limit is 3 pictures, after the user has selected 3, all other images will have `alpha = 0.3` to indicate that this image is not selectable. (Scroll all the way down to see a demo)

First of all, this is the code I have:

PickerPhotoCell (a custom collection view cell):

```
class PickerPhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var selectable: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.alpha = selectable ? 1 : 0.3
        }
    }
}
```

PhotoPickerViewController:

```
class PhotoPickerViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    ...
    var photos: [PHAsset]()    // Holds all photo assets
    var selected: [PHAsset]()    // Holds all selected photos
    var limit: Int = 3

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Suppose I have a func that grabs all photos from photo library
        photos = grabAllPhotos()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell ...
        let asset = photos[indexPath.row]

        ...

        // An image is selectable if:
        // 1. It's already selected, then user can deselect it, or
        // 2. Number of selected images are < limit
        cell.selectable = cell.isSelected || selected.count < limit

        return cell
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PickerPhotoCell

        if cell.isSelected {
            // Remove the corresponding PHAsset in 'selected' array
        } else {
            // Append the corresponding PhAsset to 'selected' array
        }

        // Since an image is selected/deselected, I need to update
        // which images are selectable/unselectable now
        for visibleCell in collectionView.visibleCells {
            let visiblePhoto = visibleCell as! PickerPhotoCell
            visiblePhoto.selectable = visiblePhoto.isSelected || selected.count < limit
        }
    }
}
```

This works almost perfectly, except for one thing, look at the GIF:

[image]

**The problem is**

After I've selected 3 photos, all other visible photos have `alpha = 0.3`, but when I scroll down a little more, there are some photos that still have `alpha = 1`. I know why this is happening - Because they were off-screen, calling `collectionView.visibleCells` wouldn't affect them & unlike other non-existing cells, they did exist even though they were off-screen. So I wonder how I could access them and therefore make them unselectable?

Comment: TableViews, CollectionView reflect the state of there cells through the backing datasource provided to it. You have to update your model list not changing the appearance of cells.

Comment: When you configure the cell in `cellForItemAt:` you need to set the alpha according to your selection state.

Comment: update the model and set the alpha in cellForItemAt indexPath

Comment: Thanks guys. But what about the visible photos? They are already loaded because they're on screen, and `cellForItemAt:` will not get called until I start to scroll, meaning that those visible photos will not have `alpha = 0.3` when selected photos reach limit. Should I call `collectionView.reloadData()` after every selection/deselection in `didSelectItemAt:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to store your state in the cell itself, by doing this: `if cell.isSelected...`. There are no off screen cells in the collection view, it reuses cells all the time, and you should actually reset cell's state in `prepareForReuse` method. Which means you need to store your data outside of the UICollectionViewCell.
What you can do is store selected `IndexPath` in your view controller's property, and use that data to mark your cells `selected` or not.

pseudocode:

```
class MyViewController {

    var selectedIndexes = [IndexPath]()

    func cellForItem(indexPath) {
       cell.isSelected =  selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath)
    }

    func didSelectCell(indexPath) {
        if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath) {
            selectedIndexes.remove(indexPath)
        } else if selectedIndexes.count < limiit {
            selectedIndexes.append(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is no need to maintain the list by yourself. allowsMultipleSelection and indexPathsForSelectedItems will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I get what you mean now. One more question though, on click a cell, a blue mark is shown in the top-right corner, how do I make this happen? 1. Inside of my custom cell, I do `override var isSelected: Bool { didSet { ... } }` or 2. In `didSelectCell` function, I call `collectionView.reloadData()`?, or there's another way?